# Image overflows fixed size grid in Chrome when image spans entire grid and grid-template-row is 1fr

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a fixed-size grid - say width:300px,height:100px with just one row and column. I want to place an image in that grid that covers the entire grid. By itself this use case seems pointless but I narrowed it down from an issue I observed when trying to create an image gallery using nested grids.

**Issue:**

If I set `grid-template-rows:1fr` on the grid, depending on the size of the grid and image, in some cases the image overflows the grid in Chrome but not in Firefox. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSiv6.png) are some grid and image size combinations I tried.

If I set `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr` or a fixed size like `100px`, the image doesn't overflow.

There is no overflow when the grid size is not fixed.

Interestingly, if the height of the grid is longer than the width, there is no overflow regardless of the height:width ratio of the image.

I have a [codepen](https://codepen.io/bakulm/pen/wvyVaqG) where I compared the behavior of fixed size grid with fluid size grid and simple fixed-size div. I have links of 3 images : square, rectangle - w>h and h>w to try different combinations.

Relevant HTML snippet:

```
<div class='fixed-grid'>
   <img src='image1.jpg' alt='Image'>
</div>
```

Corresponding CSS:

```
 .fixed-grid {
      width:300px;
      height:100px;
      /* overflow: hidden; */
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      border:5px solid goldenrod;
    }

  img{
      object-fit: cover;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      grid-column: 1/-1;
      grid-row: 1/-1;
    }
```

Any ideas why the overflow should happen only in Chrome and how to fix/avoid it?

Thanks.

Comment: min-height: 0; to the image ?

Comment: Thanks! That seems to fix the issue. 
But why? What  causes the overflow in the cases I mentioned and not in others?And why is the problem only in Chrome?